upvotes tally is not reflected in actual tally in vote summary tab
On Characteristic impedance of a BNC jack to jack adapter (that I answered with acceptance from the op) I should have 45 points but, the pull-down vote summary only reflects 30 points: -

There are no downvotes as I write this question either.
What could be the reason?
It's been like this for several hours now.
Please feel at liberty to call me daft for missing something obvious.
https://i.sstatic.net/B8kXs.png

Looking at the timeline of the answer, there are 2 "accept" events, which seems odd.  Perhaps the OP accepted, then unaccepted, then accepted again.  This seems like a bug.

@toolic interesting. Just found out how to look at timeline now. Thanks for that tip.

No problem.  Also, the question timeline shows 3 accept events, and the other answer timeline shows 1 accept.

Sounds like a bug then. At around the time of the question being accepted I noticed that my tally had increased by 11 (eleven) and that seemed very odd to me hence, why my attention was drawn to it.

I'm too busy with a queue of other mod stuff to take on this issue, so I won't attempt an answer. (You won't want to wait for this to get to the top of my list). Hopefully another mod has the bandwidth to take this quicker than me. || However for the record (in the hope that it's useful) the OP accepted & unaccepted your answer. Then they accepted & unaccepted another answer. Then they accepted your answer again. All in quick succession. So it's an unusual, but valid, sequence of events since OPs are allowed to move their "áccept" between answers. Personally I'd wait & check again tomorrow.

I find it noteworthy that two of the three accept-event timestamps are highlighted in red (click).

@Velvet - Hi, The red background on that pair of events (09:14:57 & 09:15:01) indicated that the áccept (09:14:57) was unáccepted (09:15:01). That's what the red background indicates. That is the first áccept (and then unáccept) that I mentioned in my comment above. The second áccept you can see, without the red background (09:15:03) is the 2nd áccept on that answer (the 3rd áccept overall, including the other answer) and that one has not (at least at time of writing this :) ) been unáccepted. Hope that clarifies for you :)

As I put in my response to your flag, your profile does show the correct reputation increase. It's probably just a bug in the inbox feed.

@SamGibson Thanks for the clarification :)

I now see the "accept" in the reputation tab.

@toolic good spot so, it took about 24 hours to catch up!

@Andyaka - Hi, (a) After the update from toolic and your confirmation, I've deleted obsolete comments which are no longer applicable. (b) I've constructed an answer which you have the option to accept, to effectively close the topic. (c) I have a memory from long ago (too vague for me to give it any attribution - it might have been on the main Meta?) that we should wait 24 hrs to allow certain overnight processes to run, before worrying about voting problems. This is why I commented yesterday to "check tomorrow". I couldn't be sure it would help, but it seems to have done so this time too.

Summarising the new information kindly added in a comment by toolic, which show that the problem has now resolved itself:

I now see the "accept" in the reputation tab.

and confirmed by the OP, Andy aka:

good spot so, it took about 24 hours to catch up!


I've set this to "Community wiki" so that I don't get any credit for upvotes on it, as it is just constructing an answer from other people's material.

My last comment under the question was a nod to you BTW.

@Andyaka - Thanks. Sorry I couldn't be more confident that waiting would help, or it would have been a clearer recommendation yesterday. We'll know for next time!
